# Cordova network plugin no funciona en un controller

Tags: angularjs, ionic, cordova, ng-cordova

Estoy utilizando un **plugin** con el fin de obtener el estado y tipo de conexión de mi dispositivo móvil a través de una aplicacion. Pero el plugin solo funciona dentro de `$ionicPlatform.ready`, al menos eso me ha pasado, cuando lo ejecuto dentro del `controller` el resultado del tipo de conexion es `unknow`.

Este es el plugin: [Netwrok Plugin ngCordova](http://cordova%20plugin%20add%20cordova-plugin-network-information)

#### Codigo

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])
    .run(startApp)
    .controller('networkCtrl', networkCtrl);

startApp.$inject = ['$ionicPlatform', '$cordovaNetwork'];

function startApp($ionicPlatform, $cordovaNetwork) {

    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
        }

        if (window.StatusBar) {
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }

        var netInfo;
        netInfo = $cordovaNetwork.getNetwork();
        console.log(netInfo);

    });

}

networkCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$cordovaNetwork'];

function networkCtrl($scope, $cordovaNetwork) {

    var netInfo;
    netInfo = $cordovaNetwork.getNetwork();
    console.log(netInfo);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomado de la [documentación](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html#deviceready): (traducción mía)

> ... Esto significa que la web app puede, potencialmente, invocar código Cordova Javascript antes que su contra-parte nativa se halla cargado completamente.
>   El evento `deviceready` se dispara cuando Cordova esta totalmente cargado ...

Lo que quiero decir es que el controller puede iniciarse antes que Cordova esté completamente cargado. La técnica es poner el código que lee el estado de la red dentro del evento `deviceready`. No te preocupes por si el evento se carga demasiado tarde (es decir después que se halla lanzado el evento) por que Cordova invocara el callback inmediatamente si el evento ya fue lanzado antes.

```
function networkCtrl($scope, $cordovaNetwork) {

  // $ionicPlatform.ready(function() { <- falta injectar
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
    console.log(
      $cordovaNetwork.getNetwork()
    ) 
  });

}
```

Comment: Si señor, es esto correcto, ya lo había puesto y funciona, gracias de igual forma.